# Create new SSH keys w/ new server, or use existing key?

Tags: github, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

In the `myhome/.ssh/` directory are local SSH keys for my personal GitHub account, the directory has the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files that allow me to authenticate with GitHub.

I am setting up a server (compute engine on GCP), and this server needs these keys because it needs to authenticate to my GitHub to pull a repo. Should I either:

1. transfer over / SCP the currently-existing `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub that I have locally onto the server, and use those on the server.
2. create a brand new SSH key from on the server, and use this key. Add it to my GitHub profile.
3. it doesn't matter, either (1) or (2) is fine.
4. or something else?

**(2)** seems like the right approach, but we are not certain.

Comment: SSH key pairs are like passwords. Typically use a different key pair. Use tools like Bitvise to manage your key pairs for SSH connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed option 2. As a best practice, you should not share the same private key.

Go ahead and generate a new SSH key following the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh